# Getting error "Argument is not a literal String" while running genstrings command

Tags: objective-c

While trying to run the following command: `genstrings ./Classes/*.m` on a Terminal, I am getting the following error: `Argument is not a literal String`. Does anyone know what the problem might be?

Comment: Please show us the line in question.

Comment: I've always wnated to suppress this when I do it on purpose, where I set up stringVariable (perhaps concatenating couple strings) and then use

NSLocalizedString(stringVariable, @"comment")

to do the localization.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check your source files if you have something like

```
NSLocalizedString(stringVariable, @"comment");
```

Maybe you should have a literal string in this function:

```
NSLocalizedString(@"literalString", @"comment");
```

Comment: Close, but the error was that the quotation mark was not correctly formatted, Thanks

Comment: In my case I had above  with the string variable but it was commented out.  Still genstrings saw it fyi

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I got the error because I had NSLocalizableString in a comment (e.g. "// TODO: Change line above to NSLocalizableString before going to production"). Apparently, genstrings does not ignore comments.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, importing the `NSLocalizedString` function in Swift caused this issue:

```
import func Foundation.NSLocalizedString
```

I just temporarily used `import Foundation` and it worked.